# (JSON-LD) Adding recommended fields that are not visible on page

Tags: seo, google, json-ld

I'm using the type "GovernmentOrganization" to describe some content on my homepage.  I have subOrganizations of type "GovernmentOffice" listed and the following fields filled out for each of them: name, telephone, and image.  All of these items are present on my homepage.

However, putting my code through https://search.google.com results in warnings saying I should include further fields: address and priceRange.  This information is not visible on my homepage, but is included deeper within the site.

Is it okay to add this to my homepage JSON-LD when it's not visible, as long as the subOrganization has other visible information?  Or does everything included need to be visible? And if so: what are best practices for handling this while avoiding duplication/extra-maintenance of JSON-LD across multiple pages?

Homepage Example:

```
{
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "GovernmentOrganization",
        "name": "Sample Government",
        "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress": "123 4th St.",
            "addressLocality": "Los Angeles",
            "addressRegion": "CA",
            "postalCode": "90001"
        },
        "image": "https://sampleGov.com/img1.png",
        "url": "https://sample.com",
        "sameAs": [
            "https://www.facebook.com/sampleGov/",
            "https://twitter.com/sampleGov"
        ],
        "SubOrganization":[
        {
            "@type": "GovernmentOffice",
            "name": "Board of Supervisors",
            "telephone": "+1-818-111-2222",
            "image": "https://sampleGov.com/img2.png"
        },
        {
            "@type": "GovernmentOffice",
            "name": "Assessor",
            "telephone": "+1-818-222-3333",
            "image": "https://sampleGov.com/img3.png"
        },
        {
            "@type": "GovernmentOffice",
            "name": "Election's Office",
            "telephone": "+1-818-444-5555",
            "image": "https://sampleGov.com/img4.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Is it okay to add this to my homepage JSON-LD when it's not visible,
as long as the subOrganization has other visible information?*

Do not do this. This can be perceived as hidden content from users and this is a **[spam signal for Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9044175)**:

> Structured data found on hidden content   Structured data found on
> elements that are not visible to the user.

*what are best practices for handling this while avoiding
duplication/extra-maintenance of JSON-LD across multiple pages?*

Google requires structured data to represent the main content of the webpage to which the data refers:

Important: Google does not guarantee that your structured data will show up in search results, even if your page is marked up correctly according to the Structured Data Testing Tool. Here are some common reasons why:

> ...The structured data is not representative of the main content of
> the page...
>
> Relevance
>
> Your structured data should be a true
> representation of the page content.

And the information from the Google guide that I indicated first:

> Structured data does not match content    Content on pages found to be
> different than structured data on the page.